# How to map requests from a path?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I have the following domain:

`https://example.com`

I want, when the following /path/ is hit:

`https://example.com/path/subpath/?param1=value1&param2=value2`

​

the content from this url to be served:

`https://example.com/subpath/?param1=value1&param2=value2`

​

without performing a redirect.

​

I have tried using an alias like this:

​

`location /path/ {`

`alias /home/forge/example.com/current/;`

`}`

​

where current is a symlink pointing to the latest release:

​

`current -> /root/example.com/releases/timestamp/`

​

But it doesn't work. it gives 404.

How can I achieve this?

The entire server block:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com;
    server_tokens off;
    root /home/forge/example.com/current;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;
    
    location /path/ {
        alias /home/forge/example.com/current/;
    }
    
    location / {
        gzip_static on;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com-access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/example.com-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;
    

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
    gzip on;
}
```

Comment: Use `rewrite ^/path(/.*) $1;`, this will strip the `/path` prefix from the processed URI. Put this directive **outside** the `location` block.

Comment: Hey @IvanShatsky but performs a redirect. It changes: https://example.com/path/ to https://example.com

Comment: Usually it should do only the internal URI rewrite without `redirect` or `permanent` flags, see the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite), but it can depend on your config/backend and you didn't include your full nginx config to your question.

Comment: I included the entire nginx configuration now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason why

```
rewrite ^/path(/.*) $1;
```

didn't work as expected. But if you want to use an `alias` solution instead, you should take into account that regex matching locations have a greater priority than prefix ones and any request for `/path/subpath/index.php` would be processed by `location ~ \.php { ... }` rather than `location /path/ { ... }`. You can override this with `^~` location modifier using a second nested PHP handler:

```
location ^~ /path/ {
    alias /home/forge/example.com/current/;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason it didn't work for me. But your answer makes sense to me from what I see (even though I am not a professional server admin)